# Using curl in shell script to create a name variable and running a for loop to add file content to an api, but only name is getting added

Tags: bash, shell, curl, command, sh

```
function creation() {
   for file in *.yaml; do
      name=$(echo "$file" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
      echo "$name"
      curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-yaml' -u username:"$password" --data-binary "@$file" https://example.com/rules/"$name"
   done
}
```

I have tried removing double quotes from variable names but it still doesn't work, only the name of the file which is in $name gets added in rules not the remaining content.

Can someone help me out to add the remaining content as well.

Comment: can you try: `echo "$file" | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-yaml' -u username:"$password" --data-binary @- https://example.com/rules/"$name"`  in your `for` loop?

Comment: Are you sure the payload is provided correctly for the API? The shell itself looks fine, though `name=${file%%.*}` would be simpler.

Comment: @chepner - This didn't work through Jenkins.

Comment: @User123 - I tried but this also didn't work.